# VBA code to use Vlookup inside of a for loop on a collection

Tags: excel, vba

I am having difficulty integrating a Vlookup into a for loop I have to display each value of my collection.  The background on this if that I have to check the cells in a column to make sure they are a qualified mnemonic.  I have the list of all the mnemonics possible so if the vlookup returns a value then its a mnemonic.  To make this a quick check, my collection will display the distinct values and I am trying to display the vlookup result right beside the distinct value.  I can't get the vlookup to loop through and I think I also need an error handler, I just can't pin down exactly how to do it.  The way its coded right now it will work for the first value but it won't loop, and also if the first value isn't a mnemonic it won't work.

```
Sub QualityAssurance()

    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rngCell As Range, _
        rngMyData As Range
    Dim clnMyList As New Collection
    Dim varMyList As Variant
    Dim strMyList As String
    Dim Mtch As Variant

    'Assumes the dataset is from A2 to A[whatever the last row in Column A is].
    'Change to suit
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngMyData = Range("A2:A1000" & lngLastRow)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next 'Need to ignore errors as a Collection can only contain unique values
        For Each rngCell In rngMyData
            clnMyList.Add Item:=rngCell.Value, Key:=CStr(rngCell.Value)
        Next rngCell
    On Error GoTo 0 'Nullify error handler

    For Each varMyList In clnMyList



        If strMyList = "" Then

            strMyList = varMyList & " = " & Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(varMyList, Sheet1.Range("P2:Q8"), 2, 0)


            Else:


            strMyList = strMyList & vbNewLine & varMyList

        End If
    Next varMyList

    MsgBox strMyList

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drop the `WorksheetFunction` you will not get a run-time error in the event there's no match, and you can instead test the return value to see if it's an error:

```
Dim r

'....
For Each varMyList In clnMyList

    If Len(strMyList) > 0 Then strMyList = strMyList & vbNewLine

    r = Application.VLookup(varMyList, Sheet1.Range("P2:Q8"), 2, 0)

    strMyList = strMyList & varMyList & " = " & _
                IIf(IsError(r), "?Not Found?", r)

Next varMyList
```

Comment: @Keaton — Don't forget to mark it as the answer. That's what drives StackOverflow.